# Making a http request on android

Tags: java, android, http

I just want to make an application which makes http requests and receives responses. I have searched a lot but, I am too new to describe what I want and to find answers. If thisquestion is a mistake, or is a duplicate just warn me.

I know it is possible to make http requests using HttpURLConnection and other stuff but I want to do it like this;
Application sends lines like these;
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.google.com
 other headers etc..
Then receives response like this;
 HTTP 200 OK
 headers etc.

Is it possible ? If so, how ? Please help me, and excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If your main goal is learning, I suggest you start here:

[Android Networking - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNetworking/article.html)

If you just want to get it done fast, then I suggest you use one of the available libraries for network requests:

[Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

[Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)